# How to MySQL INSERT with prisma in Next.js API server

Tags: mysql, next.js, insert, record, prisma

I'm really a newbie on DB programming and Next.js also.

I have tried the function that received json data should be INSERTed (MySQL) with prisma in Next.js API server.
According to the explanation of the prisma, the code for inserting new record was as follows.

```
const result = wait prisma.[db_name].create({data:[json_data_name]});
```

for the PUT data [json-data_name].

For every http PUT case , the db connection count was added and after about 500 times inserting, there broke out the problem of `"Too many connections..."`.

I think that the number of record inserted is not confined to 500 or..,
I think the prisma function prisma.[db_name].create makes new connection.

How to insert 2000~3000 http PUT data into MySQL db with prisma for Next.js API server?

Answer (score 0):

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

the code above was moved out of the API handler, then the problem was finished!.
for every call of API handler , new prisma was created and used.
it means a new connection to db was created.

Thank you.